# What is solitary flower?

Tags: botany

I am Just confused whether solitary means single flower in the whole plant or one flower on one branch of the plant?

Comment: only 1 flower in 1 inflorescence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solitary flower means one flower at a specific position of a plant. It usually accompanies with another word either terminal or axillary.

Soliary terminal means a flower present at the apex of the main stem or its branches. e.g.  Trillium grandiflorum.

[image: Image1]
 <sub>Image taken from http://ohioplants.org/inflorescences/</sub>

Solitary axillary means a flower arising from the axil of a leaf. e.g. China 
rose.

[image: Image2]

<sub>Image taken from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:China_rose.JPG</sub>

[image: Image3]
 <sub>This is Sida rhombifolia. This picture is clearer.</sub>

**No. It doesn't mean that a plant has a single flower.It speaks all about the position of the flower.** Think of roses , they are solitary terminals and are in numbers in each plant, always growing at the apices of branches.

Source: My two years of learning Botany as an additional Undergraduate subject.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

*Solitary flower **could be** single or many flowers in a branch.* How many flower is in a 'branch', That is not the concept of solitary flower. The concept is about 'how many flower is there in an inflorescence (branches specialized for flowers)'

Solitary flower a flower NOT in a "inflorescence" (Cluster of many flowers together). Or in another sense, Solitary flower is an inflorescence made up of only 1 flower.

The complete terminology is: "inflorescence with solitary flower".

---

**Long answer:**

To understand what ***is*** an inflorescence with solitary flower, you need to look for what is ***NOT*** an inflorescence with solitary flower.

User @SanjuktaGhosh gave beautiful examples of solitary flowers, so I gave example of only what is **not** that.

---

[image: Brassica inflorescence,]

*Brassica* inflorescence (Raceme, which is racemose).

---

(Source http://hasbrouck.asu.edu/imglib/seinet/Brassicaceae/photos/Brassica-nigra-F-web-N1544_tn.jpg).

[image: Foeniculum sp. inflorescence]

*Foeniculum* sp inflorescence (compound umbel, which is cymose)

(Source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Foeniculum_vulgare_C.jpg/320px-Foeniculum_vulgare_C.jpg)

---

We can see now, 'inflorescence' means specialized stem axis/ branches, containing mainly flowers (and some bract leaves). In nature, flowers usually occur in such specialized stems, and look like 'cluster' (many flowers together)

---

But what if a flower occur NOT in such cluster? rather solitary, at clear distance, and the axis on which flower borne, is not distinctive from the rest plant-body?

We couldn't see any 'inflorescence'; however it is considered as an inflorescence with only 1 flower, and from growth-pattern it is a subset of cymose-inflorescence (since the only-bud is the top-bud of the stem going to be flower)

---

> Reference:
>
> 1. what we've been taught
> 2. College Botany/ VOL-1/ Gangulee, Das, Datta/ New Central Book Agency

Comment: Feel free to write explanation behind downvote. As well, I gave picture of what is **NOT** a solitary flower, so that the asker can understand from-where the concept of solitary flower came.

Comment: Inflorescence itself means a group of flowers arranged on a stalk. So writing "The concept is about 'how many flower is there in an inflorescence (branches specialized for flowers)"

is wrong. Besides "only 1 flower in 1 inflorescence" is incorrect.That's why I downvoted your answer.

Comment: Probably you are considering 'Solitary flower could not be an inflorescence'. Have I understood? However, what we've been taught solitary flower *as a subtype of cymose or definite inflorescence*. The above mentioned textbook says "When the apical or axillary bud forms a single flower, it does not form a real 'inflorescence' but this type is better included within the 'definite' group as further development is limited. In China-rose, the stalk of the flower can be distinguished into a peduncle (axis) part and a pedicel (stalk) part with an articulation between the two".

Comment: May be you are right. I've too seen that somewhere. I'll edit my answer after referring to my Studies in Botany. Well I've removed my downvote.

Comment: Its Ok thank you very much however at any time you feel free to downvote if you found something wrong. However Colg. Bot. kept space that, it is not true-inflorescence where Studies (V1) directly classifies it in cymose. Also thanks for mentioning an example of terminal cyme. I was not aware of that.